# How can I check if a value in a smaller array is in a larger array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, algorithm, search

I have two arrays:

symbols - smaller array
fetchedSymbolsArray - larger array

How can I check to see if the contents in symbols is also inside of fetchedSymbolsArray?

Lets assume

```
symbols = ["AAPL", "GOOG", "YHOO"];
fetchedSymbolsArray = ["AAPL", "GOOG", "YHOO", "MSFT"];
```

I want to check to see for duplicates, and then add any additional elements in fetchedSymbolsArray back into symbols. In this case, MSFT would be added.

Comment: where is the problem? efficiency?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you want to check whether all items in the smaller array are in the bigger array? Does order matter? What have you tried?

Comment: ISTM you want the opposite as your subject title suggests: you want to check which values in the larger array are not in the smaller array, and if you found one, add it to the smaller array. Why not simply copy the larger array into the smaller one? Why not make both sets instead of arrays?

Comment: I need to be able to maintain two different sets. Also the smaller array might have elements the larger array doesn't have. I need to be able to merge these. Can you show me an example? Having a hard time with this.

Comment: If you have two *sets* of items, then use NSSet or NSMutableSet instead of NSArray or NSMutableArray. They will prevent duplicates and have ways to find unions, sections, differences, etc. Of course you can use arrays too, but then you'll have to do all that yourself. How this can be done is shown in the answers here.

Comment: Er... I meant *intersections*, not *sections*. See NSMutableSet: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableSet . Take a look at the unionSet, IntersectionSet, etc. methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
BOOL contentIsInLargerArray = NO;
for (id *object in symbols) {
    if ([fetchedSymbolsArray containsObject:object])
        contentIsInLargerArray = YES;
}
return contentIsInLargerArray;
```

This uses -(BOOL)containsObject:(id)anObject instead of -[indexObObject:].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NSArray` method

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(id)anObject
```

to test whether or not an array has a certain object. If not, the return result will be `NSNotFound`. Here's simple way to check if one array is a subset of another:

```
NSUInteger index;
for (int i=0; i<[symbols count]; ++i) {
    index = [fetchedSymbolsArray indexOfObject:[symbols objectAtIndex:i]];
    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return NO;
    }
}
return YES;
```

Of course, this can be improved using fast enumeration or other tricks depending on the objects in the arrays, whether they are sorted, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i<[symbols count]; i++) {
    id myObj = [symbols objectAtIndex:i]; // I set id because type is unknown
    if ([fetchedSymbolsArray indexOfObject:myObj] != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"Object %@ found in fetched symbols", myObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: this only checks up to symbols count. If fetchedSymbolsArray is larger there may be a few extra elements that aren't getting compared.

Comment: Then do it the other way around.